# Owl carousel go to clicked item

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I have owl carousel v-2.0.0 with 5 items.

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/1-m.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/3-s.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/2-l.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/2-l.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/1-m.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and js to init it.

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        480: {
            items: 3
        },
        1000: {
            items: 5
        }
    }

});
```

Carousel working by drag? How to make it work by click on item(clicked item becomes the central). And how to add custom class to center item?

Comment: create a fiddle with the problem and share it please. also mention the owl carousel version.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function () {
  owlIndex = $(this).index();
  $('.owl-stage-outer').trigger('to.owl.carousel', owlIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have `loop: false` use this code

```js
$(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {
  owlIndex = $(this).index();
  $('.owl-stage-outer').trigger('to.owl.carousel', owlIndex);
});
```

if you have:

```
loop: true,
rtl: true
```

Use this code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {
  owlIndex = $(this).index();
  count = document.querySelectorAll(".owl-item.active").length;
  $('.owl-stage-outer').trigger('to.owl.carousel', owlIndex - count + 1);
});
```

If you have:

```
loop: true,
rtl: false
```

Use this code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {
  owlIndex = $(this).index();
  count = document.querySelectorAll(".owl-item.active").length;
  $('.owl-stage-outer').trigger('to.owl.carousel', owlIndex - count);
});
```

Sometimes you may need setTimeout() to work properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have a carousel with `loop: true` you might need to add a data-attribute to each slide

```
$(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function (e) {
  var position = $('[data-position]',  $(this)).data('position')
  $owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', position)
});

<div class="owl-item">
    <div data-position="{{ loop.index0 }}">...</div>
</div>
```